# Coalesce per row - get all Detail IDs grouped per HeaderRow e.g. Invoice1 | 1,2,3 Invoice 2 | 4,5,6

Tags: sql-server-2008, row, coalesce

I have the following demo data (taken from Adventureworks)

```
SalesOrderNumber    SalesOrderDetailID
SO43659             12
SO43659             11
SO43659             8
SO43659             9
SO43660             14
SO43660             13
SO43661             27
```

Is it possible to Group per SalesOrderNumber, and show the Detail IDs per SalesOrderNumber?

```
SalesOrderNumber    SalesOrderDetailID
SO43659             12, 11, 8, 9
SO43660             14, 13
SO43661             27
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7708b/1

What would be the best option for this please?
Pivots?
Cursors?

Cursor which calls stored proc for each row , e.g. [here](http://www.sqlteam.com/article/cursors-an-overview) ?
Or [this](https://web.archive.org/web/20210506192610/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/092105-1.shtml) option from 4guysfromrolla which uses user-defined function?

This is something that will be run once on only - at night -  I dont need efficiency - just any help please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is standard sql server emulation of GROUP_CONCAT in mysql

```
select  SalesOrderNumber,Ids=Stuff((SELECT ',' + CAST(SalesOrderDetailID as VARCHAR(255)) FROM t t1 WHERE t1.SalesOrderNumber=t.SalesOrderNumber   
 FOR XML PATH (''))
             , 1, 1, '' )
from t
GROUP BY SalesOrderNumber
```

[Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/36663/28)

Also,you might be intrested in http://groupconcat.codeplex.com/